# 'Server Error in / Application' while trying to run db.Execute command

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, razor

I am creating a website for a project and I keep getting this error. This part of the website is the sign up page, where the visitor enters their information and the code is then supposed to write it to the database that I have connected. I am using Visual Studio and my web page is a .cshtml file. The execute command  that I am using is as follows:

```
 db.Execute(insertCommand, name, email, number, address, psw, psw_repeat);
```

And here is the full database code:

```
@{
var name = "";
var email = "";
var number = "";
var address = "";
var psw = "";
var psw_repeat = "";

if (IsPost)
{
    name = @Request.Form["name"];
    email = @Request.Form["email"];
    address = @Request.Form["address"];
    psw = @Request.Form["psw"];
    psw = @Request.Form["psw_repeat"];

    var db = Database.Open("UserDetails");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO [dbo.details] (Name, Email, Number, DeliveryAddress, Password, RepeatPassword) VALUES(@name, @email, @number, @address, @psw, @psw_repeat)";
    db.Execute(insertCommand, name, email, number, address, psw, psw_repeat);
}
}
```

When I try to run the web page everything works and I can input details. When I click the submit button this error is displayed:

> Server Error in '/' Application. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

And this line is highlighted in red:

```
db.Execute(insertCommand, name, email, number, address, psw, psw_repeat);
```

I have looked at many similar questions and have tried adding:

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

In my web.config file but this has not helped.

Please can you help me understand what the problem is and any possible solutions you may have.
Thank you.

EDIT:
Upon further research I have tried to open the database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. When entering the server name: 'RM48-11' I receive this error again:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to RM48-11.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.             
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - 
Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink? 
ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The system cannot find the file specified

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

FULL CODE:

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@using System.Data.SQLClient;
@{
var name = "";
var email = "";
var number = "";
var address = "";
var psw = "";
var psw_repeat = "";

if (IsPost)
{
    name = @Request.Form["name"];
    email = @Request.Form["email"];
    address = @Request.Form["address"];
    psw = @Request.Form["psw"];
    psw = @Request.Form["psw_repeat"];

    var db = Database.Open("UserDetails");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO [dbo.details] (Name, Email, Number, 
DeliveryAddress, Password, RepeatPassword) VALUES(@name, @email, @number, 
@address, @psw, @psw_repeat)";
    db.Execute(insertCommand, name, email, number, address, psw, 
psw_repeat);
}
}
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
        body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container {
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: white;
    }

    input[type=text], input[type=password] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
        background: #f1f1f1;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
            background-color: #ddd;
            outline: none;
           }

        hr {
        border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .registerbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 20px;
        margin: 4px 0;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0.9;
        }

        .registerbtn:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    a {
        color: dodgerblue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
        <hr>

        <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="@Request.Form["name"]" />
        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="@Request.Form["email"]" />
        <label for="number"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="number" value="@Request.Form["number"]" />
        <label for="address"><b>Delivery Address</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="address" value="@Request.Form["address"]" />
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="psw" value="@Request.Form["psw"]" />
        <label for="psw_repet"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="psw_repeat" value="@Request.Form["psw_repeat"]" />


        <input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Register">
    </div>

    <div class="container signin">
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.aspx">Sign in</a></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you are currently not able to establish a connection to the database. Make sure your passing the correct credentials to the database when trying to open the connection. If that is all good, you may need to configure remote connections on the database.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I believe that the code has connected to the database in some sense, as when inputting the variable names in the Execute command they could be auto filled and the same for the column names of the database. If this is incorrect, is there a way I could check if a connection is being established. Also, how might I go about configuring remote connections to the database, and can this be done while still using Visual Studio?

Comment: To configure remote connections, you would need to do that through command line on the server or through the sql-server management studio interface. As far as checking the connection, what are you using to connect to the database, I typically use namespace `System.Data.SQLClient` but your code doesn't look familiar to  me as far as what class you are using for this.

Comment: I have tried putting 'using System.Data.SQLClient;' at the top of the code below the line using WebMatrix.Data; but for some reason the line is greyed out as if it is ignored. As for the remote connection aspect, this is a project for school and so I have limited access to tool to help such as a server command line. I do not think I am using a server, I have only created a database file in SQLite and I am trying to write to that. In the edit I included another error that arises when trying to connect using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I will also include the full code as well.

Comment: If you are running sql lite on your local computer as your database server, then you should use your local computer name as the server name then \ then the name of the database when trying to connect, for example `MyLocalComputer\MyDatabaseName`. Try it through sql-server management studio. Perhaps this article will help you (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-1-connecting-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: OK I just tried again in SQL Server Management Studio and I keep getting the same error. I think that the school might be blocking something, and many people with similar problems unblock something in their firewall in order to solve it. I doubt I will be able to do this at school. I will have to try to make it work on my home PC where I can use any tool I want. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yeah, if it is a security setup of your school and other students can't connect, I don't think there is much I can do to help. Talk to your teacher and see if they can direct you from here. I am voting to close this post.